# Liferay 6.1 Local staging issue

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to publish from staging to live some pages, but i can't figure out why i get this error:

```
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.lar.PortletDataException: com.liferay.portlet.journal.StructureNameException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.lar.BasePortletDataHandler.importData(BasePortletDataHandler.java:82)
```

or

```
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.lar.PortletDataException:  com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

if i have some portlet which refer to a data library. Indeed when i've tried to publish a page with the Documents and Library viewer there are missing folders and the folders ids are different from the staged ones. 
Is there some best practices for the staging with the documents and library or database configurations?
Right now I'm using Mysql 5.0.77 with InnoDB tables.

Following my portal-ext.properties

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxx?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-   8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=xxx
jdbc.default.password=yyy
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
theme.css.fast.load=false
theme.images.fast.load=false

javascript.fast.load=true
javascript.log.enabled=false

layout.template.cache.enabled=false

browser.launcher.url=

combo.check.timestamp=true

freemarker.engine.cache.storage=soft:1
freemarker.engine.modification.check.interval=0
openoffice.cache.enabled=false

velocity.engine.resource.manager.cache.enabled=false

com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter=false

com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.themepreview.ThemePreviewFilter=true

user.country=IT
user.language=it
locales=it_IT,en_US

resource.repositories.root=/mnt/hdb_disc/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1
auto.deploy.deploy.dir=${resource.repositories.root}/deploy
lucene.dir=${resource.repositories.root}/data/lucene/
jcr.jackrabbit.repository.root=${resource.repositories.root}/data/jackrabbit
dl.hook.file.system.root.dir=${resource.repositories.root}/data/document_library
```

Comment: Could you provide longer stacktraces?? Its not clear whether its happening during export or import phase.